# Form action change with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need each click the button, the form action change correctly

But if I click others buttons the form action it accumulates, example

```
 <form action="http://localhost:8000/3/approved/4/approved" method="POST" id="form-request">

 <button type="button" class="clr-empty" data-id="3">Prestar ambiente</button>
 <button type="button" class="clr-empty" data-id="4">Prestar ambiente</button>
 <button type="button" class="clr-empty" data-id="5">Prestar ambiente</button>
```

I want the form action like this, change correctly with each click on the button

```
<form action="http://localhost:8000/3/approved" method="POST" id="form-request">
```

JQuery

```
 $('.big-content').on('click', '.clr-empty', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        $form   = $('#form-request');
        $faction = $('#form-request').attr('action');
        $fid     = $(this).attr('data-id');

        //This set form action
        $('#form-request').attr('action', $faction+'/'+$fid+'/approved');
    $('#confirm').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false })
        .on('click', '#asd', function() {
            $form.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking to accumulate, so it gets accumulated. If you are sure about the first part, you can hardcode it like this:

```
$('.big-content').on('click', '.clr-empty', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $form = $('#form-request');
  $fid = $(this).attr('data-id');

  // This set form action
  $('#form-request').attr('action', "http://localhost:8000/" + $fid + '/approved');
  $('#confirm').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
  .on('click', '#asd', function() {
    $form.submit();
  });
});
```

If you want the URL to be dynamic, you can use:

```
$('.big-content').on('click', '.clr-empty', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $form = $('#form-request');
  $fid = $(this).attr('data-id');

  // Construct the URL dynamically.
  var url = window.location.href.split("/");
  url = url[0] + "//" + url[2] + "/";

  // This set form action
  $('#form-request').attr('action', url + $fid + '/approved');
  $('#confirm').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
  .on('click', '#asd', function() {
    $form.submit();
  });
});
```

The above two methods apply only if the URL is same as the domain from which the page is served. If not, you can construct the URL from the form's `action`.

```
$('.big-content').on('click', '.clr-empty', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $form = $('#form-request');
  $fid = $(this).attr('data-id');

  // Construct the URL dynamically.
  var url = $form.attr("action").split("/");
  url = url[0] + "//" + url[2] + "/";

  // This set form action
  $('#form-request').attr('action', url + $fid + '/approved');
  $('#confirm').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
  .on('click', '#asd', function() {
    $form.submit();
  });
});
```

Also, just noticed you don't need to select the form again. So your final code will be:

```
$('.big-content').on('click', '.clr-empty', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $form = $('#form-request');
  $fid = $(this).attr('data-id');

  // Construct the URL dynamically.
  var url = $form.attr("action").split("/");
  url = url[0] + "//" + url[2] + "/";

  // This set form action
  $form.attr('action', url + $fid + '/approved');
  $('#confirm').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
  })
  .on('click', '#asd', function() {
    $form.submit();
  });
});
```